# Waiting to run, over default 60 seconds. Seleinium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver

Faced a problem, wrote a program that uses selenium (chromedriver) and everything is ok. The program is written in C #. It works fine on my computer, but the program was intended for an older computer.

The old computer is rather weak and starts Seleniuim for a long time. Sometimes the startup time exceeds 60 seconds and I get an exception.

Is it possible to somehow increase the allowable waiting time before the launch of selenium?

Timeouts for loading the page, as I understand it, will not help in this case.

Comment: _startup time exceeds 60 seconds_ ... startup time of what?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I mean the start of selenium (chromedriver).

Command start: `driver.Start ();` . After this command starts chromedriver. And he does not always have time for 60 seconds.

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace for the exception you are facing at startup

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
this.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thank. I'll try it again. But I think I have already tried it and this does not affect the waiting time for the start.